# The login mail address is not yet updated even after updating the profile associated email address

Tags: support, bug, login, email, profile-page

I recently updated my mail address associated with my account.
But while logging into my account, only my old email address works in the username field. When I try with the new mail address to login, getting an error as 'user name or password is wrong'.

After logging into my profile with my old old mail address as username, I can only  see the latest updated mail address in the account settings.

Is this how the system works?